# How to set up a page and navbar template with jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I don't understand. It seems like the `<div data-role="page">...</div>` divs should contain everything on that page. But then I need to write the navigation tabs menu again and again in every page div:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#page2">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#page3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div role="main">

        <h1>One</h1>

      </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#page1">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-active">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#page3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div role="main">

        <h1>Two</h1>

      </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#page1">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#page2">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#page3" class="ui-btn-active">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div role="main">

        <h1>Three</h1>

      </div>

</div>
```

And I can't write the navbar outside the pages since it won't shown up then.

And I can't find any way to have the navbar in a separate file and include it. How is it meant to be? Do I have to code the same navbar several times or is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

change your `id` value ( `id="page1", id="page2", id="page3"` ) it should work.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was just a miss when I fixed the markup for the example code. The main question still remains.

Comment: Peter, if you want to display the `navbar` in every page just copy and paste inside each page and you are done.

Comment: So that is how it meant to be? Copy and paste the same code to every page? That's really strange. Would be so much better to have one page as template and then load content like angularJS's ng-view.